# In Ubuntu 14.04, the newest Google Chrome window display transparent and without buttons

Tags: google-chrome, xfce, window

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04, I have installed Google Chrome long time ago, and every update, now the newest version 40. When I minimize Chrome window and maximize it then the top of the window gets transparent, without buttons, and when I move mouse over it than it displays square by square to the normal - very strange behaviour. To get window normal I have to move it out of the screen and it get normal till next minimizing.

I tried reinstalling it by ppa and by deb package, it doesn't help. Do I have to remove all setting files and reinstall again? If so, where are my profile files so I can keep it, or should I remove it too?

Anybody has that issue too?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. You can turn off the direct rendering in chrome settings and everything will be fine.

Comment: Thanks, Your comment helped me! 

I can't find "direct rendering" in settings but I switched off **Use hardware acceleration when avialable** and it seems to work :)

Comment: This is a bug. It was reported: [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1309801) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=400886)